# Complete and user-friendly documentation of mmap

Tags: mmap

I see this statement here.

https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs241/sp2014/lecture/11-MemoryMapping_annotated_sol.pdf

```
MAP_SHARED
- Updates to the mapping are visible to other processes that map a shared file, and are carried through to the
underlying file. The file may not actually be updated until msync or munmap() is called
```

But this is not clear in `man mmap` as the manpage just says `MAP_SHARED        Modifications are shared.`.

Is there a document (on Mac OS X and Linux) of everything about mmap in a more user friendly fashion than the manpage? Thanks.

Comment: You need to specify which OS you are asking about.

Comment: Do you see the update?

Answer (score 0):

The man page on Linux says:

> **MAP_SHARED** 
> Share this mapping.  Updates to the mapping are visible to other processes that map
> this file, and are carried through to the underlying file.  (To  precisely  control
> when  updates  are  carried  through  to  the  underlying  file requires the use of
> msync(2).)

The man pages are designed to be complete and "programmer" friendly rather than user friendly -- that is they presuppose a basic knowledge of C and UNIX.

The POSIX man page has more detail on exactly what it means by "Modifications are shared" in the paragraph after the table with that one-phrase summary.

Comment: "User" means the "user" of the function, which is programer.